# django oauth toolkit `or` in required scopes in view

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-oauth-toolkit

I'm using drf and oauth toolkit with IsAuthenticatedOrTokenHasScope permissions as default. I have a view that contains scopes
`required_scopes = ['mod', 'admin']` When users logs into the app he have special groups which define his permission scope. So when the moderator logs into the app he gets `mod` scope. When he calls my view he gets 403 because `allow_scopes` in AccessToken model returns False. That is because the `resource_scopes` is ['mod', 'admin'] and provided_scopes is 'mod'. When method `allow_scopes` checks `resource_scopes.issubset(provided_scopes)` she returns False which is not intentional in my case.

Is there any other option without overwriting allow_scopes in AccessToken model to define that this view needs scope `mod` or scope `admin`. ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a way to get this to work. The `oauth2_provider` doesn't provided any function to achieve this. So, what I did was I defined my own custom permission which is similar to the `TokenHasScope`. So, create a file called `permissions.py` and paste the code

```
from rest_framework import permissions 
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from oauth2_provider.settings import oauth2_settings

class TokenHasAtLeastOneScope(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    The request is authenticated as a user and the token used has at least one of the right scope
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        token = request.auth

        if not token:
            return False

        if hasattr(token, "scope"):  # OAuth 2
            required_scopes = self.get_scopes(request, view)
            log.debug("Required scopes to access resource: {0}".format(required_scopes))

            # If any scope in the list of required_scopes is valid, return True.
            for given_scope in required_scopes:
                if token.is_valid([given_scope]):
                    return True


            # Provide information about required scope?
            include_required_scope = (
                oauth2_settings.ERROR_RESPONSE_WITH_SCOPES
                and required_scopes
                and not token.is_expired()
                and not token.allow_scopes(required_scopes)
            )

            if include_required_scope:
                self.message = {
                    "detail": PermissionDenied.default_detail,
                    "required_scopes": list(required_scopes),
                }

            return False

        assert False, (
            "TokenHasAtLeastOneScope requires the"
            "`oauth2_provider.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication` authentication "
            "class to be used."
        )
```

Then in your view, import permissions and set it accordingly

```
permission_classes = (permissions.TokenHasAtLeastOneScope)
required_scopes = ['mod', 'admin']
```

In the custom `TokenHasAtLeastOneScope` above, the code is similar to `TokenHasScope`. The only line that changes is

```
for given_scope in required_scopes:
    if token.is_valid([given_scope]):
        return True
```

Which loop through the items in your `required_scopes` list and if it finds a valid scope, it returns True.